# Comparison of Vector Graphic Formats

Tags: .net, vector-graphics

From [Wikipedia:Vector Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats#Vector_formats), there are several vector graphic format, such as:

- CGM (Computer Graphics Metafile)
- SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)
- ODG (OpenDocument Graphics)
- EPS (Encapsulated PostScript)
- PDF (Portable Document Format)
- SWF (Small Web Format)
- WMF / EMF (Windows Metafile / Enhanced Metafile)
- XPS (XML Paper Specification)

Has anyone had any experience working with these formats programatically in terms of:

- manipulation
- exporting to bitmap or other compressed formats (i.e. JPG/GIF/PNG)
- open source library support (specifically for .NET)
- storage
- any gotchas related to handling those formats?
- preferred format from designer peers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG and EPS are the only two I use (apart from PDF, but that's for documents not vector graphics, so irrelevant).

I prefer to use SVG if I can, as I have found it to be the most widely supported, however, I use vectors on the web, not in .NET, so this may not apply.

Comment: You said web, does it mean directly to browser without any conversion to bitmap?

Comment: Yes - well in firefox, opera and webkit browsers, SVG's will work without conversion. In IE, adobe has a plugin which will allow users to view SVG's.